# ООП дизайн приложения, MVC

Tags: java, ооп, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, javafx

Пытаюсь спроектировать ООП - дизайн будущего сетевого приложения - текстового чата. 
Использую:

1. Язык Java
2. JavaFX в качестве GUI
3. MVC в качестве основного шаблон проектирования

Соответственно имеются пакеты **Модель**, **Представление** и **Контроллер**. 
Появляется пара вопросов относительно структуры такого приложения:

- Куда относится созданный мною класс для работы с сетью (отвечает за сетевое соединение и получение сообщений с сервера) ? Модель или Контроллер? Была мысль создать его как синглтон и никуда не относить. Но много слышал, что это не соответствует принципам ООП.
- Какие способы, помимо синглтона, существуют для защиты от создания множественных инстанций класса? Например как тот же класс для работы с сетью. Или класс для работы с файловой системой. В тех случаях, когда не вижу смысла в создании нескольких инстанций данных классов. Если же таковых не существует, то какой лучший способ пристроить их в общую структуру, говоря о ООП? Возможно непонимание идёт от того, что данные классы не являются объектами моделируемой области (как например контакт, сообщение и т.д.)
- Правильно ли я понимаю, что контроллер служит для взаимодействия Модели и Представления? Напрямую они взаимодействовать не могут?

Answer (score 1):

Привет.
Класс для работы с сетью - он вообще никак не относиться к MVC. У тебя должа быть модель, которая поставляет данные контроллеру, который должен отображать. Но логика работы с сетью у тебя должна происходить в моделе, т.к. это относится к бизнес логике.

В синглтоне нет ничего плохо, но это будет узкое место твоей системы.

И да, контроллер связывает view и model. Если говорить правильнее, но для JavaFx используется именно [MVP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter), а не MVC, потому что как модель неочень общаеться с view.